# Azure AD B2C Refresh Token Revoked 403

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Good morning everyone,

I Have set up an App Service in Azure and added Authentication via Azure AD B2C. So far so good everything works fine. After 1 hour though, when the token expires, I try to refresh it but then I get an error back that the refresh token has been revoked. What goes wrong here ? I have set up the backend like explained in this post : and when logging in I pass the additional parameter like so :

```
user = await Manager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(currentContext,MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "response_type", "code id_token" } });
```

This is my refresh code :

```
user = await Manager.CurrentClient.RefreshUserAsync();
```

This is the error I am getting

> {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException:
>   Refresh failed with a 403 Forbidden error. The refresh token was
>   revoked or expired. --->
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException:
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page.   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+d__24.MoveNext
>   () [0x001ec] in :0

Am I missing something here ?
Thank you

EDIT :
Here is a Screenshot of the Settings in the Portal
[image: Azure Settings]

EDIT 2 : 
Here is an error form the server logs when trying to refresh the token : 
[image: Error]

EDIT 3 : 
And here the Application Log from the webserver for the given request :

> 2017-01-18T15:08:33  PID[6344] Verbose     Received request: GET
>   https://api.near.lu/.auth/refresh 2017-01-18T15:08:33  PID[6344]
>   Verbose     JWT validation succeeded. Subject:
>   'sid:453a1ad2710466bc9873240e888d8b91', Issuer:
>   'https://api.near.lu/'. 2017-01-18T15:08:33  PID[6344] Warning     The
>   refresh request issued by sid:453a1ad2710466bc9873240e888d8b91 (SID:
>   ac22f7309036f0c07a54b1299b9601ef) failed because no refresh tokens
>   were found in the token store. 2017-01-18T15:08:33  PID[6344]
>   Information Sending response: 403.80 Forbidden 2017-01-18T15:08:34 
>   PID[6344] Verbose     Received request: GET
>   https://api.near.lu/.auth/login/aad?response_type=code%20id_token
>   2017-01-18T15:08:34  PID[6344] Verbose     Downloading OpenID
>   configuration from
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/nearauth.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_Default
>   2017-01-18T15:08:36  PID[6344] Verbose     Downloading OpenID issuer
>   keys from
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/nearauth.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_default
>   2017-01-18T15:08:37  PID[6344] Information Redirecting:
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/nearauth.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.near.lu%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=c4c15bfb-eac4-4cdc-861f-eb01594e19d2&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&state=redir%3D%26b2cPolicy%3D&p=b2c_1_default&nonce=9e243549b62f49878cc370048c6effa9_20170118151334
>   2017-01-18T15:08:39  PID[6344] Verbose     Received request: POST
>   https://api.near.lu/.auth/login/aad/callback 2017-01-18T15:08:39 
>   PID[6344] Error       An error of type 'unauthorized_client' occurred
>   during the login process: 'AADB2C90057: The provided application is
>   not configured to allow the OAuth Implicit flow. Correlation ID:
>   8336662f-8847-4f8b-bb37-6925a5d3e264 Timestamp: 2017-01-18 15:08:38Z '
>   2017-01-18T15:08:39  PID[6344] Information Sending response: 401.73
>   Unauthorized

EDIT 4: 
This is the log of a successfull login :

> 2017-01-18T19:10:14  PID[6344] Verbose     Received request: GET
>   https://api.near.lu/.auth/login/aad?response_type=code%20id_token
>   2017-01-18T19:10:14  PID[6344] Information Redirecting:
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/nearauth.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.near.lu%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=c4c15bfb-eac4-4cdc-861f-eb01594e19d2&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&state=redir%3D%26b2cPolicy%3D&p=b2c_1_default&nonce=817be561f67343688001637fa7808690_20170118191514
>   2017-01-18T19:10:30  PID[6344] Verbose     Received request: POST
>   https://api.near.lu/.auth/login/aad/callback 2017-01-18T19:10:30 
>   PID[6344] Verbose     JWT validation succeeded. Subject:
>   '1eaf9f41-1562-4ac9-9538-b893c9123087', Issuer:
>   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/07407dc1-946a-4afc-9186-84e6023ba814/v2.0/'.
>   2017-01-18T19:10:30  PID[6344] Verbose     Calling into external HTTP
>   endpoint POST
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/nearauth.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token.
>   2017-01-18T19:10:32  PID[6344] Information Login completed for 'aget'.
>   Provider: 'aad'. 2017-01-18T19:10:32  PID[6344] Verbose     Writing
>   'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'api.near.lu'. Length: 792.
>   2017-01-18T19:10:32  PID[6344] Information Redirecting:
>   https://api.near.lu/.auth/login/done#token=%7B%22authenticationToken%22%3A%22ey--REMOVED PART OF THE TOKEN--%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22userId%22%3A%22sid%3Aed01ed7507f147976aa1704783267861%22%7D%7D
>   2017-01-18T19:10:33  PID[6344] Verbose     Received request: GET
>   https://api.near.lu/.auth/login/done 2017-01-18T19:10:33  PID[6344]
>   Information Sending response: 200.0 OK

This is the error log i get when I try to refresh immediatley after logging in :

> 2017-01-23T10:55:06  PID[6344] Verbose     Received request: POST
>   https://api.near.lu/.auth/refresh 2017-01-23T10:55:06  PID[6344]
>   Verbose     JWT validation succeeded. Subject:
>   'sid:ed01ed7507f147976aa1704783267861', Issuer:
>   'https://api.near.lu/'. 2017-01-23T10:55:06  PID[6344] Warning     The
>   refresh request issued by sid:ed01ed7507f147976aa1704783267861 (SID:
>   9a6c2ee324a092937c5e2f953803e662) failed because no refresh tokens
>   were found in the token store. 2017-01-23T10:55:06  PID[6344]
>   Information Sending response: 403.80 Forbidden

Which is weird, as it can be seen in the above picture the token store is enabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that your current App Service Authentication / Authorization setup is not configured to support token refresh. A simple way to confirm this would be to enable Application Logging and look at the warning messages in the application log stream when a refresh operation fails. More details on application logging can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

See the following blog post (which I wrote) to learn more about how to update your Authentication / Authorization settings to support token refresh: https://cgillum.tech/2016/08/10/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c-part-2/#refresh. The short version is that you need to:

1. create an app key in your B2C app registration and set that as the client secret in your Authentication / Authorization "Advanced" settings for AAD in the portal.
2. Request the offline_access scope when logging in. This ensures you get a refresh token from AAD B2C when the user logs in.

Your login code should look like the following:

```
user = await Manager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(
    currentContext,
    MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "scope", "openid offline_access" } });
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, looks like I didn't read your question closely enough (I think I was reading it from my phone). I see you posted the error you got on the mobile client SDK, but what does the error/warning message say in the server-side application logs?

Comment: I added a screenshot of an error in the log that pops up in the logs when trying to refresh to the initial post... does that help?

Comment: I also added a more detailed log from the LogFiles/Application folder

Comment: Thanks, the key problem is this: "no refresh tokens were found in the token store". That's odd because if you configured a client secret like you show in your portal screenshot, then you should be getting refresh tokens sent to your app during the login handshake. Do you have any HTTP logs you can share that show the redirect to and from the AAD login page?

Comment: I did only turn on logging just now so i will have to re-login to generate them, I will do so now

Comment: Ok I added the log to the initial Question :)

Comment: Do the logs help you ? I cannot understand why my refresh is not allowed...

Comment: Thanks for the logs, they are very helpful. I investigated more in-depth and it seems B2C is not sending refresh tokens to your app, even though the App Service module is correctly using the code authorization flow. I'll need to follow up to understand how this could happen.

Comment: Actually, is it possible that in between the login and the refresh, that some other B2C policy is being invoked on this client (which doesn't implement the authorization code flow)? I wonder if that might be causing the refresh token to be overwritten. You can test this by logging in like you described and then immediately attempting to refresh the token.

Comment: Okay I will try that and get back to you,  thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok i added the log that pops up after refreshing right after successfully loging in. It is weird to see there is no refresh token in the token store, as you can see the token store is enabled in the above picture...

Comment: Aha, I think I know what the issue might be. You need to request the offline_access scope in your B2C app in order to get a refresh token. I completely forgot to talk about this in the blog post (my sample had it, but the post itself didn't talk about it)!  I've updated my answer with more info. Please give that a try.

Comment: Thank you I will try it out,  one thing Before I try it out,  in your request you left away The ""response_type", "code id_token"" entry in the dictionary,  is this no longer required?

Comment: Correct, that is no longer required after we made some simplications a few months back. If we see that you have a client secret specified in your configuration, then we'll use the "code id_token" flow automatically.

Comment: YES! Finally, it is working. After all this time, I did not believe I´d ever get it working! Thank you alot for your time and help:)

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Stupid oversight on my part. I've updated the blog posts with the full instructions.

Comment: Aww... I was hoping this would end now but now I get a new error .... it says : 2017-02-01T20:16:55  PID[6228] Critical    System.ArgumentException: IDX10401: Expires: '01/30/2017 20:26:17' must be after NotBefore: '02/01/2017 20:16:55'. So as far as I understand the token has expired, but in the Azure backend I set it to never expire... is this not supported somehow ?

Comment: One mor thing I found out: I can only use client.RefreshUserAsync(); while the token has not expired ( which is kinda useless ) , once it has expired, the method throws the error above. Calling a LoginAsync then on the client, does kind of refresh the token but with an ugly whie popup screen. Isnt that what the refreshuserasync should prevent ?

Comment: The error you mentioned is definitely a bug. Do things work properly if you configure a non-infinite expiration? FWIW, the intended behavior is that you can use an expired token up to 72 hours (configurable) to initiate a refresh. You also have the option of proactively refreshing before the expiration happens.

Comment: Ive been wrong it is not set to no expirey,  it is set to be refreshable forever so you can always refresh with a new token without having to sign in if you refresh in the (default)  60 days. So it is already set to last a defined time

Comment: But even if it is 60 days it should not be expired

Comment: Just to add a little more background, the problem you're seeing could potentially happen if B2C returns an access token that has an expiration value which we don't expect (not sure what that could be, unfortunately). After you encounter the issue, are you able to see an access_token in /.auth/me? If so, would you mind sharing it so I can look at the claims (feel free to obfuscate the signature)?

Comment: Okay so here is what I found out so far : I can only refresh a token, while my token has not expired. So by default, the ***Access Token*** has a lifetime of 60 Minutes. Within these 60 Minutes, I can successfully refresh the token by calling RefreshAsync(). However, after these 60 minutes, RefreshAsync returns with an error. Correct me if I am wrong but normally you would only refresh after the token is expired ? The ***Refresh Token*** should allow me to refresh the ***Access Token*** up to 14 days after expiration no ? I've set everything to default now. Ill now check if I still get a token

Comment: Calling .auth/me tells me I am no longer allowed to see that page, same as calling .auth/refresh

Comment: Do you have any idea what can cause this?

Comment: if you get a message saying you're no longer allowed to see that page, it most likely means there is an auth error. The details should be in the application logs.

Comment: Yes, here is the application log : https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ar9MxXcHiZ60hOk_7DuEszrWd4LwbA please note that the expiration date noted in the logs is only an hour later than the tokens creation time, so I am not able to read alot out of this...

Comment: @Tom Thanks Tom, the full error message helped me figure out exactly what's going on. This is a bug in App Service. I've opened an issue in GitHub to track this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/issues/44. The best thing I can recommend until this gets fixed is to go into the B2C portal, edit your policies, and set the token lifetime to the largest allowed time, which is 1440 minutes (24 hours). Sorry about the inconvenience, but thanks for helping me identify the problem. Let's use the GitHub issue for further communication on this.

Comment: Alright,  perfect thank you! I'll head over to github then:)

Answer (score 0):

To use the refresh user, we have to store the refresh token to the app service token store.

You can check whether there are refresh token via using the request below:

```
Get:https://{yourMoibleAppName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me
X-ZUMO-AUTH: {accessToken}
```

The access token you can get from `user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken`.

If there is no refresh token returned, you can check whether following requirements are satisfied:

1. the token store is enable
2. the response_type of request contains code
3. Developers doesn't revoke the access_token, refresh_token, user permission

And all settings well, however the the app still get the 403 error, we should prompt user to login again(refer to [Refreshing user logins in App Service Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/mobile-apps-easy-authentication-refresh-token-support/)).

And to avoid misunderstanding, when you specify you were using Azure AD B2C tenant, would you mind sharing the detail steps you protected the mobile service?

### Update( able to reproduce this issuing using the b2c app which [register this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration))

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply.

Comment: So I cannot show you the reply in the commments as it is to long , but it is not returning a refresh token. Where can I find out if token store is enabled? For 2. as you can see it does contain code. 3. I didnt revoke anything...  I created an azure ad b2c tenant that handles the login, and supplied the details to the app service so it can use it as auth.

Comment: @Tom What's the type of app register that you used to protected the mobile service? I can only reproduce this issue when I used the **native app**. If you were using **native app** please try the **web app** instead of **native app**.  And if the issue still exited, you may share the detail information about the app and how you protected the mobile service.

Comment: I had native app an web app enabled in the backend, but I now disabled the native one but I am still getting the same error... What details do you need on how I protected the mobile service?

Comment: Did you mean that you still have this issue when you use the **web app**? For the 'details' you can open the [new portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), locate your mobile service-> Authentication/Authorization->Authentication Providers(Azure Active Directory) ->Azure Active Directory Settings, and share the screen about this settings.  Please erase the sensitive data in the screenshot before you post.

Comment: Yes exactly it is all still not working. I added the pictures to the inital post I cannot add them to the comments

Comment: The **issue Url** is not correct, it should be like `https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/`, you can get this Url via open [old portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) locate your application->view endpoints->federation metadata document->navigate this page to find the **entityID** of **EntityDescriptor** element( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication)).

Comment: Hmm Ok,  I did follow this https://cgillum.tech/2016/05/27/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c/ and here he grabs the Metadata endpoint from the policy settings page... I will try your suggestion and get back to you!

Comment: I cannot find the application in the old portal, only in the new one... is ere a way to get the issuer url from the new portal?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, the **issue Url** in the orignal post should be correct for the b2c application. Based on the investigation, this issue may caused by the redirection of Azure AD( from v2.0 endpoint to the old). To clearly this issue I post the figure in the post, you can refer the detail flow about it.  And I am trying to confirm this issue.

Comment: Yes I created the application that way in the new portal!  So this is not working?  How should I create it then to make it work with the refresh tokens?

Comment: Anything new on this ?

Comment: @Tom I am still confirming this issue internally. I would come back if I have any update.